# Karma / Jasmine not finding AngularJS controller (says it is undefined)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

This is my `karma/karma.conf.js`:

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Mon Jan 04 2016 16:17:18 GMT-0500 (EST)

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      '../angular.js',
      'node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      '../post.js',
      'tests/test_post.js'
    ],



    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: true,

    // Concurrency level
    // how many browser should be started simultaneous
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

and this is my `karma/tests/test_post.js`:

```
describe('Controller: MainCtrl', function() {
    beforeEach(module('PostPageApp'));

    var ctrl;

    beforeEach(inject(function($controller) {
        ctrl = $controller('MainCtrl');
    }));

    it('Show have an add and logout function', function() {
        expect(ctrl.add).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

and this is `../post.js`:

```
angular.module("PostPageApp", ["BaseApp"])
    .controller("MainCtrl", ["$http", "$window", "BaseService", function($http, $window, BaseService) {

        var self = this;

        self.add = function() {
            BaseService.add.post(self.post, function() {
                self.cerrorMessages = BaseService.cerrorMessages;
            });
        };

        self.logoutUser = function() {
            BaseService.logout();
        };

    }]);
```

Now, when I do `karma start`, it returns this:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
        at Object.<anonymous> (/home/user/Documents/CMS/CMSApp/static/js/karma/tests/test_post.js:11:20)
Chromium 47.0.2526 (Ubuntu 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.075 seChromium 47.0.2526 (Ubuntu 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.118 secs / 0.075 secs)
```

It cannot read the property `add` of undefined even though I have the line `ctrl = $controller('MainCtrl');`. Any idea why it is saying that the controller is undefined?

Comment: No other errors? Where are the `BaseApp` module and `BaseService` defined?

Comment: Previous comment is very relevant, but you might also consider stepping through the test in the debugger, stopping at the line with the "ctrl.add" reference and "looking around".  It might not find any surprises, but it does help to confirm the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: @Phil Oh my, thanks! What I did was added `../base.js` (which includes BaseApp and BaseService) to my list of files in my karma config file. And then it worked. You can put this down as the answer and I will check it off.

Answer (score 1):

The style in which you wrote your controller is very similar in the way to which you would write a service (**using 'this' instead of '$scope'**).  I've never actually seen a controller written this way, and may make it more difficult to unit test it.

The main problem I see in your test is that the `ctrl` variable isn't being assigned to any scope in the statement,

```
beforeEach(inject(function($controller) {
    ctrl = $controller('MainCtrl');
}));
```

If you used `$scope` instead of `this`, the test would typically look like:

```
describe('Controller: MainCtrl', function() {
    beforeEach(module('PostPageApp'));

    var ctrl, scope;

    beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $scope) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        ctrl = $controller('MainCtrl', {
            scope: $scope
        });
    }));

    it('should have an add function', function() {
        expect(scope.add).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

And the controller itself would use `$scope` instead of `this`.

```
angular.module("PostPageApp", ["BaseApp"])
    .controller("MainCtrl", ["$http", "$window", "$scope", "BaseService", function($http, $window, $scope, BaseService) {

        var scope = $scope;

        scope.add = function() {
            BaseService.add.post(scope.post, function() {
                scope.cerrorMessages = BaseService.cerrorMessages;
            });
        };

        scope.logoutUser = function() {
            BaseService.logout();
        };

    }]);
```

That's one way of doing it, but it seems like you don't want to use `$scope`.  I'm guessing this is because you just don't want to expose your controller globally, which is fine.  You're way may even be better than the traditional way.  I Googled around a bit and found [Unit testing with 'this'](https://gist.github.com/traviskaufman/11131303).  It looks pretty helpful and was an interesting read; although I wish he had included the source code that he was testing.  It looks like he just used vanilla JavaScript, which is easier to test than Angular in my opinion.

I know I didn't give you a complete testing solution for the way that you wrote your controller, but I hope that I could help you pinpoint the problem and give you a better understanding of unit testing Angular controllers in general.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Currently, I added `../base.js` (which includes BaseApp and BaseService) to my list of files in my karma config file (as mentioned in one of the comments to my question) and it worked. I learned to do `var self = this;` in my controller from the book called AngularJS Up and Running, and I've been using it ever since. I actually didn't even know how to use `$scope` properly this entire time since I never learned it. Nonetheless, `ctrl.add` is now defined and the tests are successful. If I come across more problems, I'll look into the link you provided. Thanks.

Comment: Awesome!  Way to solve your own problem.  So it was a karma configuration problem; I should've noticed that. I was glad to provide some assistance.  Just don't get discouraged by Angular.  There are a lot of ways to do the same thing, it has many different coding styles, and there's not really a written set of industry standards.  I started using it a few months ago -- it has changed how I code and organize my apps in a big way.  It's been quite a trip.  Good luck on your journey!